# unable to print values of oracle.sql.ARRAY

Tags: java, plsql, oracle11g

I am getting a list of StudentIds as a `List<String>`

I convert that to a `String[]`  later,

```
String[] studentIdArray = null;
if (list!= null) { // StudentList
 studentIdArray = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]); // printed studentIdArray and print the values. its fine
}
```

Then an arrayDescriptor is declared to map the Java `String[]` to the PLSQL Table of RAW which is defined as `STUDENT_ID_TYPE`

```
ArrayDescriptor arrayDescriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("STUDENT_ID_TYPE", connection);
```

Now I get the `oracle.sql.ARRAY` out of it,

```
ARRAY studentArray = new ARRAY(arrayDescriptor, connection, studentIdArray);
```

I am **unable to find how to print the values in studentArray**, although when I print `studentArray.length()`, it returns as 1, which
I feel correct. BUt When this array is passed to my PLSQL procedure, I get custom exception.

edit: when i use the dump(), it just dumps as element[0] = [B@438620c7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the values in studentArray you could first the data as Datum[] then convert the Datum value to String by datum[i].stringValue().

```
Datum[] datumArr = studentArray.getOracleArray();

for (Datum datum: datumArr)
{
    System.out.println(datum.stringValue());
}
```